# Update all WordPress posts at once

Tags: wordpress, import

I'm trying to import all jobs, using the WP Job Manager plugin, from one site to another. I used the WordPress default import tool to do so (tried CSV, but it failed). The jobs and job applications all import properly, except the expiry dates are not being honoured. Instead, all job listings are being shown, even those past expiry. I did notice that if I go to the posts one by one and click the update button, then the expiry dates are honoured and it gets fixed. However, there are several hundred posts, so I'd like an automatic solution.

I've tried the following, with no luck

```html
 $my_posts = get_posts( array('post_type' => 'job_listing', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );

 foreach ( $my_posts as $my_post ):

   $expires = get_post_meta($my_post->ID, "_job_expires", true);
   update_post_meta($my_post->ID, "_job_expires", $expires);
   wp_update_post( $my_post );

 endforeach;
```

Comment: Reading the expiry date with `get_post_meta` and then immediately after updating it with the same value doesn't make much sense. And `wp_update_post` only affects the _posts table. Maybe the date format was not imported correctly. What is the return value for `$expires`? It should be something like `2018-09-20`.

Comment: It was that format. I actually sort found a fix for this...basically in my WP_Query, I added a meta query to check if the job_listing's expiry date is >= the current date. That "works", but of course it's not ideal. There have been several times where I've wished I could "press the update button" for all posts at once....isn't there some sort of action when that button is pressed that I could trigger?

Comment: I think it's [save_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post).

Comment: Yes, that looks right. I suppose I can invoke that with do_action(), but the question is, how do I get it to save each post? I'd imagine I'd need to pass an ID through, or set it through WP_Query, or something, so that it knows which specific post to save.

Comment: Create a WP_Query to get all posts and then loop through them and apply the save_post hook? But to tell the truth, this sounds pretty exotic, so I think the problems with your installation lie elsewhere.